# Regexp to compact default method implementations in Eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I use Eclipse Galileo to develop Java code. When implementing an interface for mocking, I often want to specify the behavior of just a few methods and retain the default behavior (do nothing or return null/0) for most. Eclipse will produce a nicely formatted default implementation like:

```
    HttpServletRequest mock = new HttpServletRequest() {

        public String getQueryString() {
            return "foobar";
        }

        public void setAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public int getServerPort() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public String getServerName() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        ... etc, etc, etc ...
```

For legibilty and cleanliness I'm looking for a regexp (for Eclipse's find/replace dialog) to clean this up, which will produce the following result when run on the above code:

```
    HttpServletRequest mock = new HttpServletRequest() {

        public String getQueryString() {
            return "foobar";
        }

        public void setAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) {}
        public int getServerPort() {return 0;}          
        public String getServerName() {return null;}

        ... etc...
```

Basically:

- remove any char/new line/tab between { and }
- but keep and rewrite "return (.*);" if there is such a thing (void methods don't have the return statement)

It's OK to hand check each replace and skip the ones I want to keep (need not be fully automated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like:

- Find pattern: `(public|private|protected)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)(\(.*\))\s+\{\s*(// TODO Auto-generated method stub)\s*(.*)\s*\}`
- Replace pattern: `$1 $2 $3$4 { $6 }`

Comment: Thanks you put me on track: here's my final solution. Find: (ublic|rivate|rotected)(.*)\{[\s\S]*?(return \w+;)?\s*?\}\s+(^\s*\w)  Replace: $1$2{$3}\R$4

Answer (score 0):

See how this is done with Adapters in swing, where the adapter is a dummy implementation of a given interface, and you then override just what you need. Gives very concise code even with anonynous classes.

Comment: Good suggestion, although I normally use EasyMock to do this. It's even better than an adapter class, but cannot be used in a 1.4 JVM environment. (my case here)

Comment: EasyMock?  Hmmm... I wouldn't.  But anyway, have you considered cleaning the Eclipse templates used to generate the code?  You can make it generate just about anything (but your {}'s will not survive an Eclipse source formatter run)